# Change footer to multiple Word files using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I would like to apply a specific footer to a number of word files located in a specific folder using VB, so that i wouldn't have to do it manually to each one

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Do you want specifically to use VBA? Why is your question tagged [vb.net]?

Comment: @ZevSpitz He said using VB in the question, I know that's only an IDE, but it is also tagged with vb.net, so I guess that's what he means.

Comment: @David Still not sure what he means. VBA language + VBA IDE? Or VB.NET + (presumably) Visual Studio? And If he wants VB.NET, he can just as easily use any .NET language -- e.g. C#, IronPython, and F#.

Comment: This is a common problem. Often people don't even know themselves what to tag or input into the question. `VBA` in title, `VB` in body and `VB.NET` in tag. It's difficult to provide a proper answer. This is why it's better if code of what they have tried is supplied so that at least we have a better understanding. As it stands this question shows no effort and is broad.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, you should:

1. Iterate through the files in the given folder using the [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat(v=vs.84).aspx); specifically, the [`GetFolder` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xtf7ta(v=vs.84).aspx) and the [`Files` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306(v=vs.84).aspx).
2. Check if the file is a Word document. If it is, then open it using the Word object model:

   - Create an instance of [`Word.Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838565.aspx) (if you don't already have one)
   - Open the document, using the [`Open` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx) via the [`Documents` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821628.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. Footers are tied to individual sections of the document. If the documents might have more than one section, you'll have to iterate over each section in the document as well, using the [`Sections` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822125.aspx). Otherwise, you can refer to the first section with `Sections[1]`.
4. Footers are accessed via the [`Footers` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194465.aspx), and passing in the appropriate footer type — a value from the [`WdHeaderFooterIndex` constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There are three types of footers:

   - The primary footer
   - The footer for even pages (if different from the odd pages)
   - The footer for the first page (if different from the other pages in the section)
5. Manipulate the footer's contents using the footer's [`Range` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192410.aspx), or other properties on the [`HeaderFooter` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194253.aspx)
6. Save the document, using the [`Save` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821625.aspx)

---

Using VBA under Word has the advantage of working under an existing Word application. However, you may be more comfortable in a .NET language (e.g. C#, VB.NET, F#, Powershell), or in another COM-enabled language (e.g. Javascript+WSH, Python, Delphi). In that case, replace the first step with whatever APIs are available in your language for iterating over the file system.

Other languages may have libraries specifically for reading and writing Word documents. In particular, .NET languages support the use of the Office Open XML SDK, for reading/writing Office documents directly, and not requiring an open instance of the application.